# Not able to get Response using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

[image]

I was trying to get the value of temp_max from the below json but I am getting null. Also, I was able to get the values of cod, message and cnt.

I was using ""response.body().getTempMax()"" to get the value. Let me know if this not the correct way.

Model class

```
public class Main {


    @SerializedName("temp_min")
    @Expose
    private Double tempMin;
    @SerializedName("temp_max")
    @Expose
    private Double tempMax;

    public Double getTempMin() {
        return tempMin;
    }

    public void setTempMin(Double tempMin) {
        this.tempMin = tempMin;
    }

    public Double getTempMax() {
        return tempMax;
    }

    public void setTempMax(Double tempMax) {
        this.tempMax = tempMax;
    }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
ApiInterface apiInterface= ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<Main> call = apiInterface.getWeather();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Main>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Main> call, Response<Main> response)
        {
            response.body();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The cnt is " + response.body().getTempMax(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Main> call, Throwable t)
        {
            Log.e("Main", t.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you paste the code for your parsing class as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your model class which you supply for parsing

Say

```
    class JSONResponse{
    int cod;
    String message;
    int cnt;
    ArrayList<Data> list;
    }


   class Data{
    long dt;
    Main main;

   }

   class Main{
   //All properties related to main class
   }
```

This is how you need to structure. Isn't it simple ?. Now when you need to access members of Main class you need to traverse all the way from JsonResponse class to Data class and access Main object and access the property.